# Export Postgres table data to Excel and append the data to MS Excel

Tags: python, excel, postgresql, psycopg2

I know we can export Postgres table data to MS Excel using Python.
But, by using Python Is there a option to export Postgres table data to MS Excel by appending the data to the existing Excel sheet data?
Note: Instead of doing it manually every day, I want to automate the process using Python, to export Postgres table data to MS Excel by appending data based on date.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data from postgres by **psycopg2** and create excel files with **xlsxwriter** .
The rest is, setting variables with DB data and placing the variables in excel file

Check the documentation for [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/) and [psycopg2](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/)

Comment: `xlswriter` is write only it cannot append data to an existing spreadsheet. To do that you would need something like [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)